# Troubleshooting slow log on of a computer?

Tags: windows, boot, performance, login

What tools would you utilize to troubleshoot a slow logon of a computer? How and why? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we get some more information? What is the OS you are working with: windows 7, server 2008 r2, etc.? Is this computer on a domain (which makes a huge difference) or in a workgroup?

Comment: Os is 7 and 8.1. Domain machine, can you explain how it makes a huge difference? how would it be different from lets say a personal machine?

Comment: Event logs to see where the delays are ...

Comment: use xbootmgr to capture a boot trace: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE and analyze it with WPA/xperfview.

Answer (score 1):

For startup app management, I like Autoruns by sysinternals, now microsoft-owned (free).  It shows every startup item and more, giving you the option to disable any items you wish.  Also have you tested the hard disk to ensure no bad sectors, as well as ensuring sufficient RAM?